# Is there a reason why MMS isn't supported in journey builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

Just hoping for some insight on why MMS isn't supported in a journey. The functionality to add images would be helpful in our journeys, but seems like we cannot add them in its current state. Is there a reason for the limitation?

Comment: I am not from Salesforce and don't have an answer. Any feature that has enough demand will probably make it through to the product. Did you search for ideas created for that? 

Just curious though - your company still uses MMS? The usage of MMS was questioned back in 2009, so I very well thought this had gone away for good in this day and age :)

Comment: MMS is not supported in Salesforce Marketing Cloud, just SMS

Comment: i figured as much, thanks! and yes @PrashanthK , it's something they would like to do, but I'll just have to push them towards being happy with SMS

Comment: As per discussion with an account exec last year MMS in Marketing Cloud is only supported in the US. I can only echo above that if things aren't used by many client Salesforce won't invest.